# Is it legal to make submitted research paper public

Tags: copyright, ieee, preprint, blog, self-promotion

I have submitted a research paper to IEEE.

Now my research supervisor is saying to make it public by writing a blog on Medium and giving a link to the paper. He also shared research paper on some channels without my consent.

I want to know

- Is it legal to write a blog on Medium regarding research paper that is not published?
- Is it affects my research paper acceptance?
- Can anyone copy it and publish it in a journal or write it on a website with his/her name?

Comment: Why do you want cross-publish in an academic journal and on a weblog? Do you hope, this will increase your citation count?

Comment: @ManuelRodriguez My supervisor has some connections with the organization whom security problem is addressed in the paper. He said that paper will reach out to public early as compared to journal publication is long. I personally don't want this as it may affect my publication and thesis submission.

Comment: Is he actually copying any *text* from the paper, or just describing the results in his own words?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni He wants to describe methodology and results in own words.

Comment: and also link paper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In which concerns publishability, it depends upon the journal policies regarding pre-prints and media coverage. However, this is not a *legal* issue - there is nothing illegal about the situation you have described.

In the case of IEEE you can see [here](http://ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/publish-with-ieee/author-education-resources/guidelines-and-policies/policy-posting-your-article/) that they allow authors to share their work anywhere.

> **Prior to submission to an IEEE publication**
>
> Authors may post their article anywhere at any time, including on preprint servers such as arXiv.org. This does not count as a prior publication.

**Caveat**: please read the whole content of the [link](http://ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/publish-with-ieee/author-education-resources/guidelines-and-policies/policy-posting-your-article/) to be aware of the full policy. They ask you to use a disclaimer that the work was submitted to IEEE:

> The following text should be included on the first page of the submitted article when it first is posted in any of the above outlets: *“This work has been submitted to the IEEE for possible publication. Copyright may be transferred without notice, after which this version may no longer be accessible.”*

Comment: So it does *not* depend on the journal's policies. The answer to the question is simply "yes".

Comment: @Najib what if the journal changes their policy in the mean time and my answer becomes obsolete for someone finding this in the future? There is a clear dependency on the policies. The best answer is that: always check the journal's policy in the official website, it may change with time or be different for different journals. And if you read the full policies you will see that they demand you to remove all the content if you get the paper accepted. So, it is a yes with a big 'but', not a simple yes.

Comment: The question asks if it's legal. Yes, it's legal, even if it is against the journal's policies.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi The main concern is about publishability not legality. However, I have edited my answer to clear state that there is nothing illegal about the situation described in the question.

Comment: Can anyone copy it and publish it some website or journal? If so how can i prove it that its my work.

Comment: @Infinity your submission to a journal is proof of ownership. Submitting to arXiv and other preprint servers is also proof of ownership. Using something from arXiv without giving due credit is clear plagiarism.